# UIViewContentMode options in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, image, swift, uiimageview

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding and/or implementing images with a particular fill type into my project. The background is a UIImageView. Here is a screenshot of my app's "Profile" page

[image: App Profile Page]

The image is pulled in from Facebook, using the Facebook graph. The image is a 720x720 square.

The image looks decent in the smaller circle, however the background version doesn't fill the way I would expect it to. Despite having tried all of the "ScaleAspect______" methods, the background looks as shown.

My understanding was that ScaleAspectFill would do what I want, which is the scale the image down until either X or Y is the size of the frame and then crop the remainder out. That's how it's shown on the Apple Docs.

I have added and removed clipsToBounds to the ImageView, neither of which made any changes.

The image I'm working with can be found here:

https://graph.facebook.com/10152976336695409/picture?width=640&height=640
downloaded

EDIT: Clarified that the background is a UIImageView type.

Comment: To my understanding, aspect fit scales the image down until both X and Y are inside the container. Here's the apple docs I was referencing: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW1

Comment: background image is displayed in UIButton or UIImageView?

Comment: Background us a UIImageView.